# Sudo not allowing me to install stuff

Tags: command-line, package-management, xfce4-terminal

So, I am using UBUNTU in a virtual machine. I tried this command in Xfce Terminal(I installed it) - `sudo pacman -S make patch`.But it is showing this after entering the correct psw -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF0EB.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to add yourself to the `sudo` group.

As root, run `usermod -aG sudo jothamrizanth`.

Also, `pacman` is Arch Linux's package manager. On Debian & Ubuntu, you can use `apt install make patch` to install `make` and `patch`.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia4nH.png - Getting an error.

Comment: Is it because I failed thrice to get access to do that `pacman` thing??

Comment: You need to run the `usermod` command as root. (Run `su` to become root)

Comment: how do i do it?? I dont know

Comment: Ok, I tried this, `su usermod -aG sudo jothamrizanth` but it is saying that `-a` was an invalid option

Comment: Run just `su`. This gives you a root shell. Then run `usermod -aG sudo ...` in that shell.